# Run shell command with java that also opens the terminal window in raspberry pi

Tags: java, shell, terminal, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

So with java, you can execute a shell/terminal command using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("Command")` and it will execute the command in raspberry pi or another os. But I'm looking for a way to execute the command so it would also open the terminal window automatically so I could easily see the output. In windows 10 you can do this `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /K " + "command");` and it works but how do you do the same thing in a raspberry pi that uses the raspberry pi os?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

You can use `lxterminal -e bash -c 'command'` Which will launch a new terminal and execute the command in it. You can put that inside the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("")`